# Scrapy installation fails when collecting Twisted / Centos 7

Tags: python, linux, centos, scrapy, twisted

So guys, I just made a fresh installation of Python 3.6 on Centos 7. Created a virtual environment, when I run `pip install scrapy`, it starts collecting few other dependencies, but fails when it comes to Twisted without returning any error at all. It just freezes and nothing ever happens.

```
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from scrapy)
  Using cached Twisted-17.9.0.tar.bz2
```

I've been looking into this error since yesterday, looks like error could be related to Twisted's `tar.bz2` extension. I'm new to linux environment and Python, have successfully installed Scrapy on Windows a few months ago using the same `pip install scrapy` method. But right now, I have no clue how to proceed.

That's the guide I followed to install Python on Centos7.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Could it really be related to Twisted's compression method? If so, how can I find a way around this issue?
Huge thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't figure out how to get it extract `bz2`, so ended up installing Twisted and its dependencies manually. For future reference;

1. Download latest Twisted [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted)
2. Extract the file
3. cd to twisted/src/Twisted.egg-info
4. Run `pip install -r top_level.txt`. This will install Twisted's dependencies.
5. `python setup.py install`
6. That's it. You can now run `pip install scrapy`.